# Provide DLL path to System.loadLibrary on export

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I want to export my Java application which uses JNI interface, and loads a DLL via `System.loadLibrary("dllName")`.

The DLL file is present inside Java Project folder as well as in C drive, one of places where JVM will search for DLL at runtime.

Problem:  When I export this project out as a Jar and give it to client, client should be able to run the tool without hassles of entering a Dll file. I can't think of accomplishing this via alternative way; to provide absolute path by using `System.load("path:\\")` because I don't know where the user would download the Jar file to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the DLL in the same path that the application is running, in a system path or add its path the PATH variable before starting the app.

Comment: I am confused with your answer , can you rephrase it with an example please.

Comment: Define 'same path as the applicaton is running'. What is required is the current working directory, but it's not clear that that's what you really mean.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will load the DLL regardless of the working directory if it's loacted in the same directory as the JAR file:

```
CodeSource codeSource = MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
File parentDir = jarFile.getParentFile();
File dllFile = new File(parentDir, "my.dll");
System.load(dllFile.getPath());
```

Comment: thank you. What is MainClass here, and will your solution work if I just have the dll in project directory.

Comment: MainClass is the class name of the class that this snippet is placed in. The DLL has to be in the same directory as the JAR file. If the relative location is different, just prepend it to "my.dll", like "../my.dll" for the parent directory.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Runtime.load](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#load%28java.lang.String%29).

> Loads the specified filename as a dynamic library. The filename
>   argument must be a complete path name. From java_g it will
>   automagically insert "_g" before the ".so" (for example
>   Runtime.getRuntime().load("/home/avh/lib/libX11.so");).
>
> First, if there is a security manager, its checkLink method is called
>   with the filename as its argument. This may result in a security
>   exception.
>
> This is similar to the method loadLibrary(String), but it accepts a
>   general file name as an argument rather than just a library name,
>   allowing any file of native code to be loaded.
>
> The method System.load(String) is the conventional and convenient
>   means of invoking this method.